# Updating the database c#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I am trying to update my database, When I run my project and add a new line it works data is entered into the gridview but it does not update the actual databse. Any Suggestions?

The following code is entered into button1:

```
DataRow dr = ds.Tables["details"].NewRow();
dr["Name"] = TextBox1.Text;
dr["Price"] = TextBox2.Text;
dr["Genre"] = TextBox3.Text;
ds.Tables["details"].Rows.Add(dr);
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
localhost.Service myws = new localhost.Service();

TextBox1.Text = "";
TextBox2.Text = "";
TextBox3.Text = "";
```

Also I am using a Web service:

```
public DataSet GetDetailsSet()
{
DataSet detailsSet = new DataSet();
string database = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|/shop.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";
OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(database);
string queryStr = "SELECT * FROM details";
OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryStr, myConn);
myConn.Open();
myDataAdapter.Fill(detailsSet, "Details");
myConn.Close();
return detailsSet;
}
```

I believe I need to somehow add update in this method, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

New row is inserted into "Details" data table, which is a local copy of original table on database server. you have to update original table using update() method. Different approaches can be used.

Read this article.
[How to update a database from a DataSet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307587)